# oracle apex tabular form validation

Tags: validation, oracle-apex-5

How to add validation to a newly created row in tabular form ?. in normal method when I add validation to a tabular form column it applies to the existing records but not for newly created rows which are added after page load.

Comment: we add validation for newly created rows by using javascript functions and calling it to the columns custom attribute.

Comment: Can I use default apex tabular form validation for newly created rows (right click tabular column name-->create validation)

Comment: yes you can, but it will only run after submitting the page. if you want the validation to run simultaneously with adding values to the column, you should use javascript function.